# Convert string to DATE (JSP)

Tags: oracle, date, jsp

I have a .jsp file  (java service pages)  with a form that takes in a string date that I needed converted into a sql date datatype.

```
//Im making a data object
Date userDate = new Date();

//THIS IS THE LINE IM GETTING AN ERROR ON
//Im trying to set the date by getting the form parameter and converting the result to a date       
userDate.setDate(TO_DATE(request.getParameter("date_updated"), "YYYY-MM-DD"));

//and save the date into my database    
ps.setDate(11,userDate);
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you converting in java code?

Comment: yes @NullPointer

Comment: Are you trying to invoke a sql function inline in java code?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple way of converting string into util date and sql date in java

```
    String date_updated=request.getParameter("date_updated");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//give format in which you are receiving the `String date_updated`
    java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(date_updated);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate_updated = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    ps.setDate(11, sqlDate_updated);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke an SQL function in Java code. You should perhaps use it in the statement sent to the database, like so:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("update t set val = to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD')");
```

With that, you can just send the text representation of the date for the conversion to be done in the database (by setting a string on bind variable).

Alternatively, you can parse the date and set a date on the statement:

```
userDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("date_updated"));
//make java.sql.Date from that and then 
ps.setDate(11,userSqlDate);
```

Comment: So far this answer is the only one that answers the question “ Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?” However I disagree in suggesting the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class as a solution to the problem. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, you're welcome to edit. I'm not very much up to date with how jdbc accommodates `java.time` types, so you could perhaps edit or add a better answer...?  Thanks a lot

Comment: @OleV.V. And it's definitely the best answer this question has. Thanks for posting it

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you can use at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2, just do the following:

```
    // Create a date object holding the date from the form parameter
    LocalDate userDate = LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("date_updated"));
    // Save the date into the database
    ps.setObject(11, userDate);
```

> Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

There are a couple of problems in the line where you got the error.

```
    userDate.setDate(TO_DATE(request.getParameter("date_updated"), "YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

1. `userDate.setDate` won’t work. This method was originally meant for setting the day of month only. It takes as argument in `int` in the range from 1 through 31. The method is deprecated, meaning you should not use it. It was deprecated because it works unreliably across time zones.
2. `TO_DATE` seems to be an SQL function. You can use SQL functions in SQL and Java methods in Java, but not the other way. Java has other ways of converting strings to dates.

Both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` are long outdated. I recommend you don’t use them except if you cannot avoid a legacy API that requires one of them. An example of the latter would be if you haven’t yet got a JDBC 4.2 compliant JDBC driver (but I believe most of us have). In this case you may convert your `LocalDate` to `java.sql.Date` before passing it to your prepared statement, like this:

```
    ps.setDate(11, java.sql.Date.valueOf(userDate)); // pre-JDBC 4.2 way
```